# z-index sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to get this z-sorting to work proper.
What i want to achieve is some kind of looping/carousel. When a ".area" is getting clicked it should be placed at the very bottom z-wize. And when all elements have been set to bottom they should start to be placed up again.Dont need to be animated. Just need help with the logic.

Really like an carousel but z-wise. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/EjpSu/8/

```
var z = 1;

$(".area").each(function(e) {
    z++;
    $(this).css("z-index",z)
});

$(".area").click(function(){
    $(this).css("z-index",z--)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subtracting the total # of area divs from z-index (updated to keep z-index non-negative):

```
var n = $(".area").length;

$(".area").click(function(){
    var z = $(this).css("z-index") - n;
    if(z === 0) {
        reset();
    } else {
        $(this).css("z-index", z);
    }
});

function reset() {
    var z = n;
    $(".area").each(function(e) {
        $(this).css("z-index",z);
        z++;
    });
};    
reset();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/mTKRL/

Comment: i ache actually tried that. After all elements have beens et once it don't work anymore. Have to "reset" it some how maybe?

Comment: Does it break for you when z-index is negative? If so, it can be reset like this: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/n4WWH/1/